# NSMutableArray, checking which Value is the most abundant?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How can I check which value in an [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the most frequent?

```
Array = "0,2,3,2,2,4
```

the value = "2".

Comment: How are the number held in the array (`NSString` or `NSNumber` instances)?

Comment: intValue ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[variable.distance intValue]; )

Comment: Looks like they are stored as strings.  Of course :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `NSCountedSet` this will help with your problem.

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:youArray];

NSInteger maxCount = 0;
id maxObject = nil;

for (id object in countedSet) {
    if ([countedSet object] > maxCount) {
        maxCount = [countedSet countForObject:object];
        maxObject = object;
    }
}

return maxObject;
```

This does sound like homework though.

**EDIT**

If they are stored as strings instead of numbers then swap out `NSNumber` for `NSString` everything else works the same.

**EDIT**

Actually, I just realised that it doesn't care about what object type it is...

Latest edit will work whatever the object is.

Comment: You beat my slow fingers! +1

Comment: Man, I do miss LINQ in Objective-C!

Comment: You ought to initialise `maxNumber` to `nil` for cases where the input array is empty.

Comment: @trojanfoe In ARC strong variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yeah that's cool, however it's hard to switch my brain between C, C++ and Objective-C.  Force of habit I guess.